# How to add more date data to a Date Dimension table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am currently trying to figure out a MSSQL database.

There is a date dimension table being used by a lot of reports, and I can see that the dates stop on 2nd January 2022. So basically it is a ticking time bomb and I need to add another few years onto it.

Whoever created this date dimension didn't go any further than 2nd Jan 2022.

I would like to add another 5 or 10 years to it. Is this possible to do within SSMS? Or would it be better to create the table in Excel and then import and replace the current date dimension?

Below is an example of some of the columns in this date dimension table:

[image]

What is the best way to go around adding extra years to this?  SQL Server v10.5

Table Structure:

```
USE [MPH_DWH_Cork_Activity]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[bi_dim_date]    Script Date: 11/9/2021 3:06:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date](
    [DateKey] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateInt] [int] NULL,
    [YearKey] [int] NULL,
    [QuarterOfYear] [int] NULL,
    [MPH_MonthOfYear] [int] NULL,
    [MonthOfYear] [int] NULL,
    [DayOfMonth] [int] NULL,
    [MonthName] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [MonthInCalendar] [datetime] NULL,
    [QuarterInCalendar] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [DayOfWeekName] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [DayInWeek] [int] NULL,
    [Week Num] [int] NULL,
    [DateKey1] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Year] [int] NULL,
    [YearID] [int] NULL,
    [WeekID] [int] NULL,
    [First Date in Rolling 4 Week Period] [datetime] NULL,
    [Last Date in Rolling 4 Week Period] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__bi_dim_d__6690D80A2A4B4B5E] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DateKey1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__DateI__22401542]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [DateInt]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__YearK__2334397B]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [YearKey]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__Quart__24285DB4]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [QuarterOfYear]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__Month__251C81ED]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [MonthOfYear]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__DayOf__2610A626]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [DayOfMonth]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__Month__2704CA5F]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [MonthName]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__Quart__28ED12D1]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [QuarterInCalendar]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__DayOf__29E1370A]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [DayOfWeekName]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__DayIn__2AD55B43]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [DayInWeek]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__Week __2BC97F7C]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [Week Num]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_dat__Year__2CBDA3B5]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [Year]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__YearI__2DB1C7EE]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [YearID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bi_dim_date] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__bi_dim_da__WeekI__2EA5EC27]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [WeekID]
GO
```

Comment: When you have dimension tables, it often means the tables are not actually the production data, but rather extracts created out of production by some data warehousing product, where the data warehousing product should be able to manage this for you.  This isn't always the case, but it's common enough you should look there first.

Answer (score 2):

It is really a small matter via an ad-hoc tally table.   Without the actual table structure, we have no idea as to data types and whether or not the columns are calculated.

That said, here is a quick example

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2022-01-02'
Declare @Date2 date = '2030-12-31'

Select DateKey = D
      ,DateInt = convert(int,convert(varchar(8),D,112))
      ,YearKey = datepart(year,D)
      ,QuarterOfYear = datepart(quarter,D)
      ,MPH_MonthOfYear = '???'
      ,MonthOfYear = datepart(month,D)
      ,DayofMonth  = datepart(day,D)
      ,MonthName   = datename(month,D)
 From (
        Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@Date1,@Date2)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
      ) src
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have now added the table structure to my original post if that is some use to you. The MPH month of year is the exact same as the MonthOfYear.. the guy who created this table is now gone so I'm not sure of the reason for this column.

Comment: @SCool You've got a little work to do.  For example, I see YearKey, YearID and Year.  Are these Calendar Years, or Fiscal Years ?   My answer above can easily be  expanded and tweaked to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to modify the original script to run a new period
If you don't have it it will take you some time to rebuild it
Fortunately you seen that before December 30

Beware of special rules about 1st and last week of the year
Identify the exact rule you have to follow, it can be tricky
I don't think excel will be a great help, it can have other rules than the one you want to follow

Comment: I couldn't find the original script unfortunately.

Comment: If I did manage to find the original script, would you truncate the date table, then insert the new data? I'm just wondering what the correct process is to fix this.

Comment: Don't delete old rows, your reports need references for time dimension. A year is 365 rows not a big deal. Just run it with appropriate dates to add new years